# Python Flask: Alternative to GPIO link?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, request, gpio

I am using Python with Flask to control GPIO pins from a web server.

As of right now, you click a hyperlink with the link `/PIN/on` or `/PIN/off`. This works, as the corresponding GPIO pin turns on or off.

However, the page reloads upon clicking the link (obviously). Alternatively, I would like to send a request when clicking the link, and have it not refresh/follow the link.

Does anyone know how to implement this using Flask over Pyhon? Please use examples.

Comment: This is really a javascript question, believe it or not. You'll probably want to use Javascript to send the request to the appropriate route, triggering the gpio without having to reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about a Single Page App (SPA), to achieve this functionality you need to use something called AJAX. To use AJAX you need to use JavaScript and the XMLHttpRequest object, this allows you to make requests to the server and update the page using JavaScript, thus avoiding the page refresh. To gain a better understand of AJAX, I recommend you read [this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) There is also an example of AJAX implemented in Flask [here.](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-ajax)